# Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/springsecurity-3.1.xsd'

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have encoutered problem when I wanted to add login feature to my project and I am trying to fix it for 3 day. I read bunch of similar theards and none of them helped my problem. Changing to versionless xsd doesn't help as well.

**security-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/springsecurity-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/springcontext-3.2.xsd"
>


<sec:http auto-config="true">
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/products/add" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/products/add" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>
<sec:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager>

<sec:authentication-provider>

    <sec:user-service>
        <sec:user name="Admin" password="123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    </sec:user-service>

</sec:authentication-provider>

</sec:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

**Pom file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.packt</groupId>
<artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
</project>
```

Comment: `spring-security.xsd` and not `springsecurity.xsd` the same applies to `springcontext`

Comment: Thanks alot man, Such an embarrassment...